# URL rewriting, url masking

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite, laravel-5, url-rewriting

I want to know if there is a solution to rewrite url from http://domain.com/username to http://username.domain.com?

Also I want to mention, that this should be done automatically, when a new user registers.

I am using laravel 5 framework by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Please check solutions below

**Using .Htaccess**

Read Solution at http://laravel.io/forum/03-11-2014-routing-for-subdomain

**Using Laravel Controllers**

Read at 
http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/dynamic-subdomain-routing
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/routing-for-optional-subdomain-domain-and-optional-tld?page=1

You will need to understand Laravel Basic Routing first. Read Laravel Documentation at

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It didn't solved my problem so far, but I've got a useful information from you. Thanks.